# R Shiny dashboard shows incorrect datetime compared to base data

Tags: r, shiny

R Shiny shows completely unrelated and wrong datetime compared to the baseline data: The output of baseline data:

```
data %>% group_by(Day = day(SampleTime), device_user) %>% 
   mutate(flag = case_when(lag(Value) != Value ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>% filter(flag == 1) %>% 
   mutate(trip_status = case_when(Value == 1 ~ 'ON', TRUE ~ 'OFF')) %>% filter(VariableDescription == 'IGNTIONSTATUS') %>% 
   select(-ThingID)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   Day, device_user [1]
  VariableDescription Value SampleTime          device_user   Day  flag trip_status
  <chr>               <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>       <int> <dbl> <chr>      
1 IGNTIONSTATUS           1 2020-12-27 17:25:03 BST            27     1 ON         
2 IGNTIONSTATUS           0 2020-12-27 17:35:01 BST            27     1 OFF        
3 IGNTIONSTATUS           1 2020-12-27 18:26:20 BST            27     1 ON         
4 IGNTIONSTATUS           0 2020-12-27 18:33:30 BST            27     1 OFF        
5 IGNTIONSTATUS           1 2020-12-27 18:56:48 BST            27     1 ON         
6 IGNTIONSTATUS           0 2020-12-27 19:04:06 BST            27     1 OFF
```

Dashboard:

[image]

Server Code:

```
function(input, output) {

    tripsfilter <- reactive({
        
        if(input$selectaDayForTrip == 'All' & input$selectvehicleForTrip == 'All'){
            tripstatusfilterdata <- lagsdata %>% filter(VariableDescription == 'IGNTIONSTATUS')
            
        } else if(input$selectaDayForTrip == 'All' & input$selectvehicleForTrip != 'All'){
            tripstatusfilterdata <- lagsdata %>% filter(VariableDescription == 'IGNTIONSTATUS' & device_user == input$selectvehicleForTrip)
            
        } else if(input$selectaDayForTrip != 'All' & input$selectvehicleForTrip == 'All'){
            tripstatusfilterdata <- lagsdata %>% filter(VariableDescription == 'IGNTIONSTATUS' & day(SampleTime) == input$selectaDayForTrip)
            
        } else {
            tripstatusfilterdata <- tripstatusfilterdata <- lagsdata %>% filter(VariableDescription == 'IGNTIONSTATUS' & day(SampleTime) == input$selectaDayForTrip & device_user == input$selectvehicleForTrip)
        }
        return(tripstatusfilterdata)
    })
    
    output$tripStatus <- renderDT({
        datatable(data = tripsfilter()  %>% group_by(Day = day(SampleTime), device_user) %>% 
                      mutate(flag = case_when(lag(Value) != Value ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>% filter(flag == 1) %>% 
                      mutate(trip_status = case_when(Value == 1 ~ 'ON', TRUE ~ 'OFF')), options = list(pageLength = 30))
    })

}
```

UI Code:

```
dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = 'Telematics Packages'),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(id = 'menu',
                    menuItem(text = 'Trip Status', tabName = 'trips_status', icon = icon('road')),
                    conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.menu == "trips_status"',
                                     selectInput('selectaDayForTrip','Select a day for trip status', choices = c('All', unique(day(lagsdata$SampleTime))), selected = max(day(lagsdata$SampleTime))),
                                     selectInput('selectvehicleForTrip','Select a Vehicle to view trip status', choices = c('All', unique(lagsdata$device_user))))
        )
    ),

dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = 'trips_status',
                fluidRow(
                    box(tags$style(type = "text/css", ".box-body {height:80vh}"), width = 12, solidHeader = TRUE, title = 'Trips Progress', DTOutput('tripStatus',width="100%",height="100%"))                                                
                ))
    )
)
)
```

Sample Data:

```
structure(list(VariableDescription = c("IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", 
"IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", 
"IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", 
"IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", 
"IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", 
"IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", 
"IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", 
"IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", "IGNTIONSTATUS", 
"IGNTIONSTATUS"), Value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), 
    SampleTime = structure(c(1609070103, 1609070163, 1609070223, 
    1609070272, 1609070332, 1609070392, 1609070452, 1609070467, 
    1609070527, 1609070588, 1609070648, 1609070701, 1609073780, 
    1609073840, 1609073900, 1609073960, 1609074020, 1609074080, 
    1609074140, 1609074200, 1609074210, 1609075608, 1609075668, 
    1609075728, 1609075788, 1609075848, 1609075908, 1609075968, 
    1609075983, 1609075992, 1609076046), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Kolkata"), device_user = c("BST", 
    "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", 
    "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", 
    "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", 
    "BST", "BST", "BST")), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = "data.frame")
```

There are more than 10 devices, the amount of time difference is also not constant between devices, some are 2 hours, others are 3. So it can't be about timezone issues. Could someone help me in correcting the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datatable` converts the datetime to UTC/GMT time. If you want data to be in local time or any other timezone one way would be to convert them to character.

Compare the output of these two chunks.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(SampleTime = as.character(SampleTime)) %>%
  DT::datatable()
```

[image]
and

```
df %>% DT::datatable()
```

[image]